# Converting Double from Delphi/Pascal to Java

Tags: java, linux, windows, delphi, double

I need to read a binary file created in Windows SO, using Delphi/Pascal language. I know that this file is fixed length and the first 8 bytes is a double. I copied this file from a Windows SO to a Ubuntu SO. When I try to read this file, inside Ubunto SO, using java language I see:
Double = 84000

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -126, -12, 64]
```

So I create the same double (84000) inside Java, running Ubuntu SO:

```
Double yourDouble = (double) 84000;
byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(yourDouble);
```

Looking at bytes array I see:

```
[64, -12, -126, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Clearly, the byte array is inverted. Is there anyway to read this file? Or i need to invert the byte array?

EDIT:
Is It inverted because of Big Endian e Little Endian?

Comment: Windows SO & Ubuntu SO is a mystery for me.

Comment: @user246408 An SO in Linux is the same as a DLL in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java, publicly at least, represents data in big endian byte order, even if internally it may use a different byte for reasons of efficiency. Delphi, on Windows at least, is little endian. So you need to reverse the byte order.

You'll have the same issue for integral data types too. And any 16 or 32 bit character data.

Comment: I thought big endian and little endian was about CPU architecture.

Comment: Big vs little endian applies in the hardware architecture ***AND*** in the byte stream order used in serialization.

Comment: @Rubber The thing is, what happens on the hardware is hidden from you. When you serialize a double to a byte array in Java, big endian byte order is mandated by the java spec.

Comment: Just look at the history of Java for the real answer to "why big endian?" Java was developed by Sun Microsystems (before being acquired by Oracle). Sun produced their own Unix systems based on their own CPU design, the Sparc. That CPU was a RISC big-endian architecture. It stands to reason that the first target implementation of the Java virtual machine was on a Sparc system, and so the big endian requirement "leaked through".

Comment: @Allen How would Emba deal with a situation where they had to put Delphi on a big endian machine? I'm curious how it would be tackled.

Comment: So far we've not had to deal with it. ARM is little-endian, however some of them allow you to select it. The good thing so far is that the world is converging into an x86/64 and ARM world where little-endian is is the norm. Endian-ness only really matters when streaming or trying to chop-up memory accesses into bytes and words and dwords. If you've ever done any network socket API programming, you'll quickly see that you have to deal with the fact that IP addresses are actually arranged in big-endian format.

Comment: Sure, it's simple in cases where the user does type-casting of a 4-byte integer entity to grab the high word or the low word. Just re-declare structures to take endian-ness into account. However, for cases where the user is doing their own bit-twiddling, there is not much we can do except provide some hint that they're targeting a big-endian system (like a conditional define).